# PrettyPhoto hash link

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I use prettyphoto js.
Standard script is :

```
function setHashtag(){
    if(typeof theRel == 'undefined') return;
    location.hash = theRel+'/'+rel_index+'/';
};
```

If i change it to:

```
function setHashtag(){
    if(typeof theRel == 'undefined') return;
    location.hash = theRel+'='+rel_index;
};
```

Id doesnt work. Why?

Clearly, if I use URL like this -

> http://mysite.ru/video/twd.php#id/1/
>   it works, and modal opens ok.
>   but when i try to open link like this 
>   http://mysite.ru/video/twd.php#id=1
>   nothenig happens... only load a page.

Comment: nope. 
it works ok with '/' and '='
but if i share this link (in twitter for example) link with '/' opens modal window right, but with '=' nothing happens
i hope u understand me)

Answer (score 0):

```
hashIndex = getHashtag();
hashRel = hashIndex;
hashIndex = hashIndex.substring(hashIndex.indexOf('=')+1,hashIndex.length);
hashRel = hashRel.substring(0,hashRel.indexOf('='));

hashtag = (url.indexOf('?id') !== -1) ? decodeURI(url.substring(url.indexOf('?id')+1,url.length)) : false;

location.hash = theRel + '=' + rel_index;
history.pushState(0, 0, location.hash.replace('#','?'));
```